# export local array value to global value

Tags: javascript, arrays, global-variables, local-variables

I am trying to return the value of array by using console.log(array); it return empty value []. any suggestion is greatly appreciate it.

```
var array = [];
var maxLength = 3;
var delay = 250; //I shortened your delay
var ticker = {}; //I'll use this to simulate your ticker object

var looper = setInterval(function() { 
      ticker.BNBBTC = Math.random(); //populating your ticker property w/random value

      if (array.length < maxLength) {
         array.push(ticker.BNBBTC);
      } else {
         console.log("Stopping the looper.");
         clearInterval(looper);
         console.log("Here are the contents of array");
         console.log(array);
      }
}, delay);
```

Comment: `return the value of array by using console.log(array);` ... console.log returns undefined, so using console.log will never allow you to return the array ... since the array is being pushed to in a setInterval you can't simply return the value - suggest you create a function with that code and either return a Promise or use a callback

Comment: I tried the following method but I am not sure about how to create the first function? var array = [];
 
function first(){  
     
array.push(3);
    
}

function second(){console.log(array);}

first();
second();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with a callback

```js
const fn = callback => {
  var array = [];
  var maxLength = 3;
  var delay = 250; //I shortened your delay
  var ticker = {}; //I'll use this to simulate your ticker object

  var looper = setInterval(function() {
    ticker.BNBBTC = Math.random(); //populating your ticker property w/random value

    if (array.length < maxLength) {
      array.push(ticker.BNBBTC);
    } else {
      console.log("Stopping the looper.");
      clearInterval(looper);
      console.log("Here are the contents of array");
      callback(array);
    }
  }, delay);
};
fn(result => {
  console.log(result);
})
```

or with a Promise

```js
const fn = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  var array = [];
  var maxLength = 3;
  var delay = 250; //I shortened your delay
  var ticker = {}; //I'll use this to simulate your ticker object

  var looper = setInterval(function() {
    ticker.BNBBTC = Math.random(); //populating your ticker property w/random value

    if (array.length < maxLength) {
      array.push(ticker.BNBBTC);
    } else {
      console.log("Stopping the looper.");
      clearInterval(looper);
      console.log("Here are the contents of array");
      resolve(array);
    }
  }, delay);
});
fn().then(console.log)
```

You'll notice with both of these methods there's no reason to "pollute" the global namespace - something that you should be avoiding as much as possible in modern javascript - the only global in either case is the `const fn`